# How do I return a blank if there is no data on a separate sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want data in `F16` sheet `STATISTICS` to only be present when there is a `W` in column `P` on sheet `TRADE LOG` between the dates 01 Feb 2021 and 28 Feb 2021.

If there is no `W`I want `F16` to return a blank.

This is the formula I am currently using:

`=IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("E",ROW()))), "", COUNTIFS('TRADE LOG'!P:P,"W",'TRADE LOG'!B:B,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'TRADE LOG'!B:B,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28)))`

I anyone could suggest any tweaks that would allow me to do this I would be grateful.

Comment: Just in case you were not aware, "" and " " are technically not the same as blank. ISBLANK on a cell containing "" is false where a comparison of a cell to "" will be true (ie. A6="").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place the following formula in F16 and replace "Data" with the formula or data you want displayed when there is a "W" in your hard coded date range.  Do note that the "W" in the P column is not case sensitive.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('Trade Log'!P:P,"W",'Trade Log'!B:B,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'Trade Log'!B:B,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28)),"DATA","")
```

You may also want to look at placing the month you want to check or date range as a cell reference instead of a hard coded date, but you will need to make that decision based on your needs.

[image: POC]

In order to display the "W"s within date criteria, replace "Data" with the part of the formula you used to make the count in the first place.

```
COUNTIFS('Trade Log'!P:P,"W",'Trade Log'!B:B,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'Trade Log'!B:B,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28))
```

When substituted into the original formula it will look like the following:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('Trade Log'!P:P,"W",'Trade Log'!B:B,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'Trade Log'!B:B,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28)), COUNTIFS('Trade Log'!P:P,"W",'Trade Log'!B:B,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'Trade Log'!B:B,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28)),"")
```

## Alternate Approach

You could also just use the countifs formula and use custom formatting for the cell so that a zero value is displayed as nothing or space.

Comment: Hi Forward Ed, that works great however instead of DATA being displayed, I simply want the COUNTIF to count the W's in column P in sheet TRADE LOG. What would need to be added to achieve this?

Comment: @Excelnewman All the Ws or just the Ws in the date range?

Comment: Just the W's within the 01 Feb 2021 to 28 Feb 2021 date range please